# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: No address associated with hostname

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I dockerized my Laravel project using [this YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjMIvDSCElw&ab_channel=ScalableScripts)

The app runs on GCP `Cloud Run` but without SQL connection

When I login I get `SQL` error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: No address associated with hostname (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = email@email.com and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)
```

I setup:

```
GCP CloudSQL container
Created a Database and imported my tables
Created VPC Network
Created SQL connector
```

And added all connections to these resources in `Cloud Run` deployment

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        container_name: 'processtooldb'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 'trim-mile-380809:europe-west3:tooldb'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'tool_db'
            MYSQL_USER: 'pt_db_admin'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring

WORKDIR /app
COPY composer.json .
RUN composer install --no-scripts --ignore-platform-req=ext-zip
COPY . .

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

Kepp getting the same `No address associated with hostname` error over and over
Any help?

Comment: 1) Why does your question include `docker-compose.yml`? Cloud Run does not use that file to deploy services. 2) Cloud Run also only supports one container per service. You cannot run multiple containers (laravel.test - mysql) in one service. 3) Cloud Run is stateless, which is not a good environment for a database. 4) You can run a Laravel app in Cloud Run, the database must be hosted elsewhere such as Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley for the reply. I mentioned in question that I'm not facing any problem with Cloud Run.  the db is hosted somewhere else already in CloudSQL just not able to connect to it with wrong host error, can you suggest better implementation of the docker-compose file?